# Understanding the Rails 3 Directory Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've found several sites online that explain the DIR structure of a Rails app, but I'm still not clear on a few, mainly:

```
/vendor
/lib
/public
```

What should go where? I want to know the best practice. For example, I have jQuery plugins, should those be located in /vendor? /public? /lib? I've read all 3 from different sites online.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-directory-structure.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vendor is third party code / libraries, so, yes, a good place for jQuery plugins.

Public is for static assets, stuff that gets no benefit from being in the asset pipeline.

Lib is generally used to contain your code that is not specific to the app. i.e. stuff you use in multiple apps. There is a trend to put domain logic in lib e.g. domain classes not based on ActiveModel. Gary Bernhardt (https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/) is a proponent of this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You've confirmed a few things with me, so I understand how it's laid out a little better now. I just wanted to ensure that I was putting everything where it should go.

Answer (score 4):

Typically the contents of /public are directly served by the web server (nginx, apache etc.) without intervention from rails, so traditionally all of your static assets (images, stylesheets, javascripts etc.) went in here. You can still put your javascript in there but it's a bit old fashioned.

Rails 3.1 introduced the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) which changed all of this. Assets in app/assets, lib/assets and vendor/assets all get servers up by the asset pipeline. Normally your application specific assets would go in app/assets and 3rd party libraries (such as a query plugin) would go in vendor/assets. If you were developing your own set of jquery plugins you might put them in lib/assets. Assets will 'work' no matter where you put them though - it's just a question of organisation.

Gems can also have their own asset folders, for example the jquery-rails gem bundles jquery and allows your app to serve up jquery without actually copying it into your app. I find this even neater than putting things in vendor/assets.